# Angularjs no data available in table issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using angularjs data table where every time before rendering the table i receive "no data available in table" message. After the message the table shows data in the expected way.so how to fix the issue? 
check  [demo](http://sdm.22web.org/)

```
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http,DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,DTColumnDefBuilder) {

            $scope.service = service;
            $http.get('ajax/list.php').success(function(data){
            $scope.cus_list = data;      


            $scope.vm = {};


            $scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('order', [0, 'asc']);
            $scope.vm.dtColumnDefs = [
                                          DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notSortable()
                                      ];


    });
});
```

Comment: That's not the error I'm seeing. I see a "digest already in progress" error as a result of the `$scope.$apply();` that's in the controller in that page (not shown in your question).

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove that.check  now.

Comment: Not seeing any errors now

Comment: "no data available in table" message remains only for a few second after that is disappear and render the table, may be that's why you didn't notice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table is rendering before the data has come back from the server. You might want to use `ng-if` on one of the HTML elements to wait until the data is available:

```
<table ng-if="userList" datatable="ng">
```

**Edit** The message you don't like has a CSS class of `dataTables_empty`. So maybe you can only show it with CSS if both the data has loaded and there are no rows showing in the table.

Comment: is there any  other way to prevent the rendering before data has come back ?

Comment: Unless datatables has its own way, you can either not render (using `ng-if` or `ng-show`) or hide the message using CSS.

Comment: If datatables has a way of letting you know how many rows it is currently showing, then you could use CSS to show the message only when both the data has loaded AND no rows are showing.

Comment: @query Using ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: @PraveenMP i am using ng-cloak but don't know why this is not working in this issue

Comment: @FrankModica can you tell why table is rendering first and and data coming later ? is it due my code or the server is responsible for the late reply ?

Comment: `ngCloak` is for when you want to hide bindings like `{{ }}` before Angular is initialized. That won't help here. The table renders before the data has arrived because the HTTP call that gets the data is asynchronous- we don't know how long it will take for the data to arrive. So the HTML loads and creates the datatable while we are waiting for data. `ng-if` stops an HTML element from being created until some condition is true. In this case, our condition is that data must exist.

Comment: @FrankModica I think using resolve would be the right approach to  solve this kind of issues. resolve will wait the data to load from the service and  once the data is available and it will load the view.  https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/17/resolve-in-angularjs-routes-explained-as-story/

Comment: If there is routing in this app, and if there is nothing else that must be displayed on the page before the data arrives, then yes resolves are an option.

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me, The table is rendering before the data has come back from the server. You might want to use

```
<table class="table table-bordered" *ngIf="mynotes" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
```